# low speed in textPaint measure text width android

Tags: android, performance, text, width

I use textpaint for measuring text width but it is happens frequently and `textPaint.measureText(string)` is very slow.

How can I change my code to speed up the measuring?

This is my code -

```
void appendLines(String text, TextPaint textPaint){

    String[] linesWords = text.split(" ", -1);

        for (String linesWord : linesWords) {
            appendWords( " " + linesWord , textPaint);
        }

    }

    boolean firstWord = false;
        private void appendWords(String text, TextPaint textPaint){
            if (text.contains("<br/>")) {
                text = text.replace("<br/>", "");
                haveBrTag = true;
            }

            float textWidth = textPaint.measureText(text);


            if(textWidth + currentLineWidth + marginRightLeft> pageWidth) {
                finalizeAppend(textPaint);
                firstWord = true;

            }
            if (currentLineWidth == 0){
                text = text.replace(" ", "");
                firstWord = false;
            }
            currentLineWidth += textWidth;
            currentLine.append(text);

            if (haveBrTag){
                finalizeAppend(textPaint);
                haveBrTag = false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: what do you need `measureText()` for? whats your goal?

Comment: I need to show a large text in a textview inside of viewpager so i need to split My text in to pages and To Acive this goal I need To measure text Width

Comment: you dont have to do that: use `StaticLayout` class

Comment: I used StaticLayout but it is slow agiain with large text.In this link I Explained What happend : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017361/staticlayout-too-much-time-takin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44017361/staticlayout-too-much-time-taking)  @pskink

Comment: `split` method is never used